# Using max() with Django query

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Is there a way to make this query work with Django?

```
stage = Task.objects.filter(id = input_stage.id)\
            .update(start_date = max(data.get('start_date'), F('start_date')),
                    finish_date = max(data.get('finish_date'), F('finish_date')))
```

Now I get an error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'F' and 'datetime.date'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `max` between two fields in a database is in Django the [**`Greatest`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest), so the query should read something like:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest

Task.objects.filter(
    id=input_stage.id
).update(
    start_date=Greatest(Value(data.get('start_date')), F('start_date')),
    finish_date=Greatest(Value(data.get('finish_date')), F('finish_date'))
)
```

You also might want to convert the `data.get('start_date')`, etc. to `date` objects.

Mind that a [**`.update(..)`** [django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#update) does *not* return a `QuerySet`, but:

> (...) and returns the **number of rows matched** (which may not be equal to the number of rows updated if some rows already have the new value).

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Comment: I see you have updated your answer. Is there any difference to use `Value` or not using it?

Comment: @Chiefir: well "*The Zen of Python*" says "*explicit over implicit*", I think it is more safe to wrap it in a `Value` given the fields contain a value, and not a field name, since some of these database functions tend to pick the fieldname. So I think `Value(..)` is at least safer (although at the moment I can not test it). If you however `data.get('start_date')` contains the field name, then it should be an `F(..)`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. P.S. `data` is just a dict with date.